# Sitecore publish pipeline, how to catch if publish failed to target Database

Tags: sitecore

Issue: Unable to catch if publish item to TargetDatabase fails.

In sitecore UI, When I publish an item from master database to web database(Target Database), I wanted to check if publish was successful before it shows in UI.

looking at the following post from John West about the pipeline order: 
http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/08/intercept-item-publishing-with-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

I've added the following publish item processor:

```
 <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="BOTWLibrary.Pipelines.EvaluateResult, BOTWLibrary"/>
```

In EvaluateResult.cs

```
public class EvaluateResult : PublishItemProcessor
{
    public override void Process(PublishItemContext context)
    {
       // check if publish was successful.
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the publish fails it will set the results operation to none, as well as give a reason for the unknown publish action. This isn't a guarantee that the publish failed but I think it's the closest you'll get.

```
public class EvaluateResult : PublishItemProcessor
{
    public override void Process(PublishItemContext context)
    {
        // check if publish was successful.
        if(context.Result.Operation == PublishOperation.None)
        {
            throw new Exception(context.Result.Explanation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dan I tried to check  'context.Result.Operation == PublishOperation.None'  but, it's never got into the if statement if there is a sql exception : _Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database_

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your issue a little bit. Is an exception being thrown and you're wanting to suppress the error?